# Gatsby: Setting reading environment variable in html.js

Tags: environment-variables, gatsby

I've followed the guide here(https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/environment-variables/) and managed to set an environment variable(`MY_ENV_VAR` in `.env.development`) and use it in any of the page files. However I can't use it in the `html.js` file(duplicate from `.cache/default-html.js`). `MY_ENV_VAR` is always `undefined` in `html.js`. Any idea what I could be doing wrong? Or is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [docs that you've provided](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/environment-variables/) that there are some server-side environment variables and client-side environment variables. While the first one runs in the server and therefore they are available in all Node files (`gatsby-node.js`, `gatsby-config.js`, etc) the second one runs in the browser and must be prefixed with `GATSBY_` as shown in:

> In addition to these Project Environment Variables defined in `.env.*`
> files, you could also define OS Env Vars. OS Env Vars which are
> prefixed with `GATSBY_` will become available in browser JavaScript.

In your case, you've set a server-side variable which is perfectly functional in your Node files and `undefined` in your browser. The different behavior between `develop` and `build`, the code doesn't behave in the same way. For further details you can check the [Overview of build process documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/).